# Msg 4145 SQL Server An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected,near 'END'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I dont know why it's giving me this Error, cant find anything

This is my code

```
@cid int,
@sid char(9)
AS

BEGIN

update StudentCourses
SET mode=0
where(select CourseId,StudentId from StudentCourses where CourseId=@cid 
and StudentId=(Select PkId from Students where ID=@sid))

END
GO
```

Comment: what is your where condition ???

Answer (score 1):

Not to sure what exactly your table structure look like, Its a guess but I think you need to do something like this...

```
@cid int,
@sid char(9)
AS

BEGIN

update StudentCourses
SET mode=0
where CourseId=@cid 
and StudentId IN (Select PkId 
                  from Students 
                  where ID=@sid)

END
GO
```

**Problem with your query**

> 1- **WHERE Clause** where(select CourseId,StudentId from Stude.... Your Sub-query is simply retrieving data , it not giving a condition for your main query to filter rows its just returning data this is one issue causing error in your query.br/>
>
> 2 - **Sub-Query with possible multiple values** and StudentId=(Select PkId from Students where ID=@sid) this sub-query can return multiple values . in that case you cannot use the '=' equals operator you need to use 'IN' Operator , like I have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

your where statement makes no comparison so it is not valid - it cannot be true or false

Comment: which one of the where statment is not valid?

Comment: the primary where clause

Comment: Not sure but I think your statement should be: 
    update StudentCourses
    SET mode=0
    where CourseId=@cid 
    and StudentId=
     (Select PkId from Students 
  where ID=@sid)

Comment: @Mörre: my answer did point at the source of the error, the clause after the where statement returned a table of values which cannot be evaluated as true or false for the current row. I went on to discuss that with the author and I believe that we resolved the issue with my suggested alternative sql